# Installing material-design-lite with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, material-design

I'm working on a MEAN stack (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node) and would like to use Google's Material Design Lite library. According to [the docs](http://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html#download) one should run

`npm install material-design-lite --save`

Inside an NPM project to enable use of the mdl components. I get following error:

```
npm ERR! Failed at the material-design-lite@1.0.0 install script 'napa mojombo/clippy'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the material-design-lite package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     napa mojombo/clippy`
```

So there's a problem with `napa mojombo/clippy` anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try to find the root cause with verbose

```
npm install material-design-lite --save --verbose
```

Comment: Gives a lot more info, but basically says the same 'napa mojombo/clippy sh: napa: command not found' ..

Comment: looks like a bug in the package. follow https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/pull/947

Answer (score 0):

`npm install material-design-lite@1.0.0-3`
this should work, [issue here](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/859)

Comment: Now available version `1.3.0`